# Explain a uniprocessor / multiprocessor locking system used in operating systems

Tags: operating-system, multiprocessing, locking

So I'm looking at a course into operating systems, and I'm currently at a chapter about synchronization.
I came across these functions as a way to aquire and release a lock, and the course showed these methods and asked why this would work on a uniprocessor system but not on a multiprocessor system. Of course I understand that it works on a uniprocessor system, but I don't understand what would happen on a multiprocessor system. Can someone explain this please, thank you!

Here are the 2 methods that would supposedly not suffice on a multiprocessor system:
Lock acquire method

```
void lock_acquire(lock_t *lock) {
    disable_interrupts();
    while (*lock) {
        enable_interrupts();
        disable_interrupts();
    }
    *lock=1;
    enable_interrupts();
```

Lock release method

```
void lock_release(lock_t *lock) {
    disable_interrupts();
    *lock=0;
    enable_interrupts();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

beceause disabling interrupt does not prevent a second processor on the bus from accessing your critical region between the read and the write, infact on a multiprocessor system you should use the `TSL` or the `XCHG` istruction that prevent this problem blocking the memory bus, like this:

```
mutex_lock:
 TSL register,mutex
 CMP register,#0
 JZE ok
 call thread_yield
 JMP mutex_lock
 ok: ret

mutex_unlock:
 MOV MUTEX,#0
 ret
```